# Simplifying a numeric vector to a factor with two levels in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a 'double' vector

```
c(-5,-5,-5,-5,1,2,-5,4,3)
```

I want to set all values having -5 as one factor, and all others as another factor, so that I would have something like:

```
[1] w w w w b b w b b
Levels: b w
```

I have a way of doing this but it is not elegant, are there any recommended approaches for this type of conversion?

Comment: `factor(x = (c(-5,-5,-5,-5,1,2,-5,4,3) == -5), labels = c("b","w"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `forcats` contains a lot of nice functions for working with factors. One way to solve your problem is like this:

```
library(forcats)
v1 <- as.factor(c(-5,-5,-5,-5,1,2,-5,4,3))
fct_recode(fct_other(v1, keep = "-5", other_level = "b"), w = "-5")
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with

```
factor(c("w", "b")[(v1 >0)+1])
#[1] w w w w b b w b b
#Levels: b w
```

---

Or using `ifelse`

```
factor(ifelse(v1 > 0, "b", "w"))
#[1] w w w w b b w b b
#Levels: b w
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(-5,-5,-5,-5,1,2,-5,4,3)
```